# add animation to listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I am populating a list view with simplecursoradapter Is there any way to add animation to items?I want something like android sound picker app which when starts items appearers one by one ..Here is my adapter

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(mySQL, null);

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, 
            columns, new int[] {R.id.list_item_text_sub,R.id.list_item_text_main,R.id.list_item_text_id,R.id.list_item_img}, 0);

adapter.setViewBinder(new CustomViewBinder());
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at this project by Sony Ericsson developers:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/06/23/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-3/

and take a look at those links:

http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2009/10/listview-and-listactivity-layout.html

http://graphics-geek.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/devbytes-listview-animations.html

Comment: You welcome, you may want to upvote/accepts if it helps you : )

Answer (score 2):

Refer this Lib It Work
[Library Link](https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView/tree/master/library)

Example

[Animation Example](http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/)

Use This in your xml file

```
<com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.JazzyListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    app:effect="fan"
    app:only_animate_new_items="false"
    app:only_animate_fling="false"
    app:max_velocity="0" />
```

Only you can change the property of "JazzyListView"
i.e

```
app:effect="Card" r "Curl" OR "Fade" OR "flip" OR "fly" OR "Grow" OR "Wave" OR "tilt"
```

etc.

Comment: If you don't wont to use external lib then You can check following for android page transformer example :  https://github.com/snehazanzane/ViewPagerPageTransformerDemo